# Problems of passing a const char* address of file to an ifstream object

Tags: c++, string, oop, ifstream

An ifstream object takes a const char*. I am giving my ifstream object the path of my file

```
ifstream in_file("E:\\myfile.csv"); //File opens
```

If i want to want to pass a string containing the address of my file i would have to convert it to a const char* first, i do that in this way:`

```
string mystr="\"E:\\\\myfile.csv\"" //mystr contains address 
const char* c = mystr.c_str();      //conversion of std::string to const char*
```

The problem lies here,

```
in_file(c);                      //cout << c; gives E:\\myfile.csv
```

I get errors on the above step... Can't figure out what is wrong. And i am working on windows

Edit: I don't get errors, the file just doesn't load

```
if (in_file.is_open())
    cout << "opened";
else
    cout << "not opened";
```

I get "not opened"

Comment: _"I get errors on the above step..."_ which ones exactly? Please make a minimal compilable sample that reproduces these errors.

Comment: There is no need to escape the characters an additional time when using a `std::string`: you'd use the same string literal as when using `char const*`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl can you elaborate a little more

Comment: Dietmar is asking why you changed `"E:\\myfile.csv"` to `"\"E:\\\\myfile.csv\""`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
string mystr="E:\\myfile.csv";
```

instead of

```
string mystr="\"E:\\\\myfile.csv\"";
```